# Extracting uniq results in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have users1 and users2 and what I am trying to do is combine them both and get a uniq result of users where there is not repetition of user. But I am not able to do so as I am getting NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass): error. How can I fix this. Please help me solve this issue.

```
def wanted_users
  @users1 = License.find(params[:ID]).users
  driving_facilities = License.find(params[:ID]).facilities.ids
  user_ids = FacilitiesUser.where(facility_id:  driving_facilities).pluck(:user_id)
  @users2 = User.where(id: [user_ids])
  @users = @users1 + @users2
  @users.uniq
end
```

user.rb

```
has_many :facilities_users, dependent: :destroy
has_and_belongs_to_many :facilities, join_table: :facilities_users
```

facility.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

facilities_user.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :facility
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "facilities_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "facility_id", null: false
    t.index ["facility_id"]
    t.index ["user_id", "facility_id"], unique: true
end
```

Comment: *"I am getting NilClass error.'* -- What is the error? Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61084707/edit) to include it. The error should show which line of code contains the issue. Without seeing that ourselves, this makes the question unnecessarily cryptic.

Comment: @TomLord Sorry about that. I have added the error message in the question

Comment: This is a massive [X&Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking about how to remove duplicates in Ruby when you really should be asking us about how to not get duplicates out of the database in the first place and how to do what is a relatively simple job without doing something like 6 database queries.

Comment: If you edit the question to show your models, the data and an expected result we can show you how to actually create a query or associations that will solve the problem effectively.

Comment: @max I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: Didn't you ask a very similar question today where I explained that HABTM does not use join models? Maybe you should start with reading the guide on assocations and the query interface which are linked in my answer. The answer here is just like in that question `has_many through:`

Comment: This is also only about half of the information required. We need all the models. An example of the data in the database and an example of what you actually want to get out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem. The user_ids were not uniq so I made them unique and then I extracted the users which solved my problem.

```
def wanted_users
  license = License.find(params[:ID])
  @users1 = license.users
  driving_facilities = license.facilities.ids
  user_ids = FacilitiesUser.where(facility_id:  driving_facilities).pluck(:user_id).uniq
  @users2 = User.where(id: [user_ids])
  @users = @users1 + @users2
  @users = @users.uniq
end
```

Comment: The original error *appears* to be that `@users1` is `nil`, and you cannot add something to `nil`. (Undefined method `+` for NilClass). I cannot be sure of this, since you still didn't post the full error message. Your new code still contains the exact same logic: `License.find(params[:ID]).users + ...` - so I don't see how this is a solution to the problem. All you appear to have done is defined a variable to reduce a line of repetition. Which is an improvement, but not an answer.

Comment: Additionally, there is bound to be a far more elegant/efficient way of doing this in *one* database query, without needing to perform any `uniq` logic in ruby. But since you didn't share what `Lincense` is, I cannot answer with any certainty on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid use `array = arrayA + arrayB`, because it will raise error as your question above.

Use operator `push` or `<<` instead of `+`